CSS y JS Vanilla: Hacer que un elemento se vuelva fixed al alcanzar el borde derecho del viewport en un scroll horizontal
Estoy trabajando en una interfaz donde tengo una tarjeta (.card-static) que quiero que me siga mientras hago scroll vertical. La idea es que esta tarjeta permanezca en su posición inicial mientras hago scroll, pero cuando su borde derecho alcanza el borde derecho del viewport, se vuelve fixed y permanece visible en la pantalla mientras sigo desplazándome hacia la derecha.
Es decir que siempre vea esa card, pero que mantenga el orden del DOM, dado que si la hago fixed, el resto de elementos ocuparian esos espacios
Codigo actual simplificado:
<div id="allCards" class="allCards">
`  <div id="cardsContainer">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card card-static">
        <!-- Contenido de la tarjeta estática -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Más tarjetas .card-container -->
  </div>
</div>

`
Css:
`
.card-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.card-static {
  position: relative; /* Comienza como relative */
  width: 250px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

`
Js:
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const cardStatic = document.querySelector('.card-static');
  const container = document.querySelector('#cardsContainer');
  let isFixed = false;

  // Obtener el borde derecho de la tercera tarjeta
  const getThirdCardRight = () => {
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card-container');
    if (cards.length >= 3) {
      return cards[2].getBoundingClientRect().right;
    }
    return 0;
  };

  function updateCardPosition() {
    const scrollX = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    const thirdCardRight = getThirdCardRight();
    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

    // Activar `position: fixed` cuando se supere el borde derecho de la tercera tarjeta
    if (scrollX + viewportWidth > thirdCardRight && !isFixed) {
      cardStatic.style.position = 'fixed';
      cardStatic.style.top = '20px';
      cardStatic.style.left = '20px';
      cardStatic.style.width = '250px';
      cardStatic.style.zIndex = '1000';
      isFixed = true;
    } else if (scrollX + viewportWidth <= thirdCardRight && isFixed) {
      // Volver a `position: relative` cuando volvemos al principio
      cardStatic.style.position = 'relative';
      cardStatic.style.top = '';
      cardStatic.style.left = '';
      cardStatic.style.width = '';
      cardStatic.style.zIndex = '';
      isFixed = false;
    }
  }

  // Event listeners
  window.addEventListener('scroll', updateCardPosition, { passive: true });
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateCardPosition);
});
`

Probe diferentes forma de hacerlo con fixed y sticky pero no lo logre.
Espero que la card me siga, dado que en lo que estoy trabajando se desplaza hacia la derecha, haciendo que si o si se necesita a esta card main por asi decirlo que se la siga para saber el enfoque si.

A que te refieres con que la card "te siga" ??? Probé tu código y le di un ancho y largo mayor a la ventana, la tarjeta queda fijada en la esquina, y queda sticky. https://jsfiddle.net/Excorpion/rd93hxqj/4/

Te doy el ejemplo, tengo multiples cards hijas que parten de la card-static, entonces la idea es que la card-static, llegue un punto en que pase a fixed para que siempre se mantenga en pantalla, intento con un fixed pero no logro hacer que cuando me desplazo a la derecha cambie de sticky a fixed.

Entonces debes agregar unas cuantas de esas otras, y un ancho y alto, para entender el problema real que tienes.
